# Как запустить memtest86+ на удалённом сервере?

Tags: linux, сервер, centos, администрирование

Есть выделенный сервер на hetzner. Недавно заглянул в логи и обнаружил там ват такие ошибки:

```
Jan  2 15:18:49 server1 kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
Jan  2 15:18:49 server1 kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec01000-0xfecfffff]
Jan  2 15:18:49 server1 kernel: PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed03fff]
```

К томуже сервер под высокой нагрузкой неожиданно умирать стал. Есть подозрения на поломку RAM. Погуглил, установил на сервер memtest86+. Но проблема состоит в том, что запуск программы можно осуществить из загрузочного меню при перезагрузке сервера. Я делаю reboot и попадаю снова на сервер - загрузочное меню не увидишь через простой reboot. Пробовал загружаться в rescue режиме - бесполезно. Вопрос, можно ди как-то запустить memtest86+ на сервере или придется писать саппорту? Может кто-то хостится на hetner и делал то-то подобное?

Comment: Только просить KVM-over-IP доступ у саппорта

Comment: Собсна об этом даже в документации есть https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/maintainance/kvm-console/

Comment: если что, то это не ошибки это просто сообщения, что подсистема Power Management не будет сохранять эти адреса при уходе в сон... вероятно они находятся в области DMA-памяти или используются под какие-то временные кеши... это нормально и ничего с этим делать не надо...

Comment: @andreymal - "KVM-over-IP доступ"
- Насколько я понимаю, для этого нужна **отдельная** сетевая карточка? Во всяком случае, на моём HP ProLiante сделано так.

Comment: @Sergey, разберитесь что ли в основах и как работает KVM (keyboard-video-mouse).